# Get latest purchased date for given product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Iam trying build a query to get latest purchase date for given product id but for now still having errors.

```
        function check_date_purchased($product_id){ 
    $args = array(
        "posts_per_page" => -1,
        "product_id" => $product_id,
        "orderby" => 'date',
        "order" => 'DESC',
        "status" => "completed",
    );
    $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
    $orders = $query->get_orders();
    foreach( $orders as $order_id ) {
       $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
       $items = $order->get_items();
       foreach ($items as $order_item){
          if ($product_id == $order_item->get_product_id()) return $order->order_date;
       }
    }
   return false;
}
echo check_date_purchased( 8070);
```

Comment: Don't use twice foreach, use a sort function.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the problem is in your loop. You're returning the purchase date as soon as you find a match, but if you want to return the latest purchase date, you should iterate through the entire list and compare the purchase date so you can check which one is the latest. Here are the changes you can make to do this:

```
function check_date_purchased($product_id){ 
   $args = array(
       "posts_per_page" => -1,
       "orderby" => 'date',
       "order" => 'DESC',
       "status" => "completed",
   );
   $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
   $orders = $query->get_orders();
   $latestPurchaseDate = false; // set this default value before loops to compare dates
   foreach ($orders as $order_id) {
       $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
       $items = $order->get_items();
       foreach ($items as $order_item) {
           if ($product_id == $order_item->get_product_id()) {
               $order_date = $order->get_date_created();
               // Compare dates to check if later than current stored latest
               if (!$latestPurchaseDate || $order_date > $latestPurchaseDate) {
                   $latestPurchaseDate = $order_date;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   return $latestPurchaseDate;
}
echo check_date_purchased( 8070);
```

Comment: did not work for me i got blank page, beside i want to filter with complete orders. isit possible to correct my code and show me where is the mistake ?

Comment: I don't know what it means that you want to filter with complete orders. In your original post, you said you wanted to build a query that would get latest purchase date for a product. In your existing query, you're just returning the order date on the first order that matches the given product id. The code I added amends this to return the most recent purchase date of the orders that match the given product id. Is this not what you're after? Please be more specific.

Comment: the query you provided will loop through all orders that much given product id even if the order is not paid and complete. beside not sure why i get white page when i test it.
thank you in advance

Comment: Oh, my code is only replacing the two for loops within your function, not the entire function body. Don't remove the code you have before the first for loop.

Comment: I edited my answer to have the complete code. Let me know if you're still having any issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, this **WC_Order_Query** class does not have a *product_id* argument. This means that the `"product_id" => $product_id` line in your `$args` array is not doing anything.
   To get orders containing a specific product, you need to iterate over each order and check if it contains the *product*, as you're already doing in your function.
2. Second, The function returns the date of the first order it finds that contains the *product*, not necessarily the *latest*. So to get the latest date, you should store the date of each order that contains the product, and return the latest one.

```
function check_date_purchased($product_id){ 
   $args = array(
       "posts_per_page" => -1,
       "orderby" => 'date',
       "order" => 'DESC',
       "status" => "completed",
   );
   $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
   $orders = $query->get_orders();
   $latest_date = null;
   foreach( $orders as $order_id ) {
      $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
      $items = $order->get_items();
      foreach ($items as $order_item){
         if ($product_id == $order_item->get_product_id()){
             if ($latest_date === null || $order->get_date_created() > $latest_date) {
                $latest_date = $order->get_date_created();
             }
         }
      }
   }
  return $latest_date;
}
echo check_date_purchased(8070);
```

In the above code, I initialize `$latest_date` as *null* before the loop. Then, for each order that contains the product, check if the order's date is later than `$latest_date`. If it is, update `$latest_date` with the order's date. After the loop, return `$latest_date`, which will be the date of the latest order that contains the product, or null if no such order was found.

This function uses the `WC_Order_Query` class to query all completed orders, ordered by date in descending order. It then iterates over each order and its items, checking if the product is in the order. If it is, it updates `$latest_date` if necessary. Finally, it returns the latest date found, or null if no date was found.

I'm not so sure if the modified code will work, But I hope you will have a hint to solve your problem.

Comment: having a fatal error on this one

Comment: thank you ill look into this code and try to use it as a hint